# android bind to AccessibilityService

Tags: android, binding, service, accessibility

I have created an android service, which is an `AccessibilityService`. From my activity, I would like to bind to that service. There is no inter process communication, so I have tried creating a local `Binder` implementation that just returns the service (as in this example http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/LocalService.html).

The problem is that `onBind` in `AccessibilityService` is `final` and I cannot override it to return my local binder.

Does this mean I need to use AIDL if I want to bind to the service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it means that you cannot bind to the service, period. You would need to override `onBind()` for AIDL.

Comment: Ah, I see. Is it not possible to bind to an AccessibilityService?

Comment: @JeffStorey: No, since they marked `onBind()` as final. They are using that themselves internally, if you take a peek at the `AccessibilityService` source.

Comment: Right, I saw that, they return their implementation of it. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You can't bind to AccessibilityService because it's `onBind()` method declared final.
BUT, you can use it's instance by storing it in a static field.

In your **MyAccessbilityService** class:

1.Create static field of the type of your AccessibilityService

```
private static MyAccessibilityService myAccessibilityServiceInstance;
```

2.Initialize it in method onServiceConnected()

```
@Override
protected void onServiceConnected() {
    super.onServiceConnected();
    myAccessibilityServiceInstance = this;
}
```

3.Clear it when AccessibilityService is turned off in onUnbind() method:

```
@Override
public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
    myAccessibilityServiceInstance = null;
    return super.onUnbind(intent);
}
```

4.Create a getter for your instance and let's add annotation @Nullable since we don't know in which period of service's life cycle it will be called

```
@Nullable
public static MyAccessibilityService getInstance(){
    return myAccessibilityServiceInstance;
}
```

and finally in your Activity or wherever you need it:

```
    MyAccessibilityService accessibilityService = MyAccessibilityService .getInstance();
    if(accessibilityService != null){
        //do smth here:
    }
```

Implemented in my app, works fine so far. 
Thanks to alanv in his reply https://stackoverflow.com/a/12557673/5502121