# Bind to AccessibilityService in Android?

Tags: android, binding, service, accessibility

I have created an android `Service`, which  extends an `AccessibilityService`. From my `Activity`, I would like to bind to that `Service`. Because I need to send information from `Service` to `Activity`. I need example code please. I have searched google and have not found anything similar, someone could put a link to an example please.

Answer (score 23):

While binding with an AccessibilityService from an Activity is possible, you'll only be able to pass AccessibilityEvents into the service. This is because AccessibilityService.onBind() is declared final, which means you won't be able to add any new methods to the binder.

There are, however, several alternative solutions.

If your activity and service are running within the same process (this is typically true if they are in the same APK), then you can communicate with a static instance of your accessibility service. Here is an example of how that would work:

**MyAccessibilityService.java:**

```
private static MyAccessibilityService sSharedInstance;

protected void onServiceConnected() {
    . . .
    sSharedInstance = this;
}

public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
    sSharedInstance = null;
    . . .
}

public static MyAccessibilityService getSharedInstance() {
    return sSharedInstance;
}
```

**MyActivity.java**

```
protected void onCreate() {
    . . .
    mAccessibilityService = MyAccessibilityService.getSharedInstance();
    if (mAccessibilityService != null) {
        // The service is running and connected.
        mAccessibilityService.doSomething();
    }
}
```

If your service and activity are in separate processes (e.g. separate APKs), then you still have a few options:

- Communicate by broadcasting [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)s from your activity to a [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) in your service
- Bind your activity to a "proxy" service within the AccessibilityService's process that communicates with a static instance (as above)

If you need elaboration on either of those, leave a comment.

Comment: I need an example in case my service and activity are in separte process.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe there is another way to communicate whith each other:

1. At `AccessibilityService` Child Class:

   > Handle the target Activity's:
   >   PackageName AND
   >   ActivityName AND
   >   **specific EventType**(eg:`AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_CLICKED`)

   ```
   @Override
   public void onAccessibilityEvent(final AccessibilityEvent event)
   {
       if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
           if (event.getEventType() == AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_CLICKED)
               if (AccessibilityUtils.findNodeInfoByViewTypeAndText(event.getSource(), "android.widget.ToggleButton", TextUtils.getString(R.string.lable_disabled)) != null)
                   getAccessibilityService().disableSelf();
   }
   ```
2. At `target Activity`:just invoke the **specific EventType**

   > invoke by user OR
   >   invoke by code

   ```
   btnEnableService.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
           {
               @Override
               public void onClick(final View v)
               {
                   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N && !btnEnableService.isChecked())
                   {
                       btnEnableService.setChecked(false);
                       txvEnabledState.setText(btnEnableService.isChecked() ? R.string.lable_service_status_enabled : R.string.lable_service_status_closed);
                       AppState.instance().setIsEnable(btnEnableService.isChecked());
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       openAccessibilitySettings();

                       btnEnableService.setChecked(!btnEnableService.isChecked());
                   }
               }
           });
   ```

### Sample Code:

- [AppEventHandler_disableSelf.java — Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/AsionTang/89.yezukz2autoinstallapp/src/2c65f4e3a4e2f266698b2026904cf57daf911365/App/src/main/java/cn/asiontang/zuk_z2_auto_install/AppEventHandler_disableSelf.java?fileviewer=file-view-default#AppEventHandler_disableSelf.java-24)
- [SettingActivity.java — Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/AsionTang/89.yezukz2autoinstallapp/src/2c65f4e3a4e2f266698b2026904cf57daf911365/App/src/main/java/cn/asiontang/zuk_z2_auto_install/SettingActivity.java?fileviewer=file-view-default#SettingActivity.java-57)