# How to bind to AccessibilityService in Mono (Xamarin)

Tags: c#, xamarin, binding, mono, accessibilityservice

I've tried and got OnServiceConnected event in ServiceConnection class. But casting IBinder to my class (it inherits Binder, that inherits IBinder) returns null if I try to do that as  "var myObject  = IBinderObject as myBinderClass;" or casting error if I try to do that as "var myObject = (myBinderClass) IBinderObject;".
Please, any working example...

MainActivity code:

```
namespace MyApp.Droid
{
    [Activity(Label = "MyApp", Icon = "@drawable/icon", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsApplicationActivity
    {
        AccessibilityServiceBinder binder;
        AccessibilityServiceConnection accessibilityServiceConnection;
        bool isBound = false, isBoundAC = false, isConfigurationChange = false;
        protected Intent ServiceIntent;
        AccessibilityServiceClass ServiceClass;

        protected override void OnStart()
        {
            base.OnStart();
            if (!isBoundAC)
            {
              accessibilityServiceConnection = new AccessibilityServiceConnection(this);
              isBoundAC = BindService(ServiceIntent, accessibilityServiceConnection, Bind.AutoCreate);
              if (isBoundAC)
              {
                Toast.MakeText(this, "AccessibilityService is Bound", ToastLength.Long);
              }
            }
        }
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            ServiceIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(AccessibilityServiceClass));
            ServiceIntent.SetPackage("android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService");
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
            LoadApplication(new App());
        }
        public class AccessibilityServiceConnection : Java.Lang.Object, IServiceConnection
        {
            MainActivity activity;
            AccessibilityServiceBinder binder;
            public AccessibilityServiceBinder Binder
            {
              get
              {
                return (AccessibilityServiceBinder)binder;
              }
            }
            public AccessibilityServiceConnection(MainActivity activity)
            {
              this.activity = activity;
            }
            public void OnServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service)
            {
              var accessibilityServiceBinder = service as AccessibilityServiceBinder; 
              //accessibilityServiceBinder is always null here
              if (accessibilityServiceBinder != null)
              {
                activity.binder = accessibilityServiceBinder;
                activity.isBound = true;
                this.binder = accessibilityServiceBinder;
              }
            }
            public void OnServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name)
            {
                activity.isBound = false;
            }
        }
        public override Java.Lang.Object OnRetainNonConfigurationInstance()
        {
            base.OnRetainNonConfigurationInstance();
            isConfigurationChange = true;
            return accessibilityServiceConnection;
        }
    }
}
```

Service code:

```
namespace MyApp.Droid
{
    [Service(Label = "MyApp", Permission = Manifest.Permission.BindAccessibilityService), IntentFilter(new[] { "android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService" }), MetaData("android.accessibility-service", Resource = "@xml/accessibilityserviceconfig")]
    public class AccessibilityServiceClass : Android.AccessibilityServices.AccessibilityService
    {
        public override void OnAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent e)
        {
            Toast.MakeText(this, "OnAccessibilityEvent", ToastLength.Short);
        }

        public override void OnInterrupt()
        {
            Toast.MakeText(this, "OnInterrupt", ToastLength.Short);
        }

        protected override void OnServiceConnected()
        {
            Toast.MakeText(this, "OnServiceConnected", ToastLength.Short);
        }
    }
    public class AccessibilityServiceBinder : Binder
    {
        AccessibilityServiceClass service;

        public AccessibilityServiceBinder(AccessibilityServiceClass service)
        {
            this.service = service;
        }

        public AccessibilityServiceClass GetAccessibilityService()
        {
            return service;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Add your service code

Comment: Done... Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't overriding the OnBind event of your service, thus the binder is null as you haven't provided an instance.

Add this to your service:

```
AccessibilityServiceBinder binder;

public override IBinder OnBind (Intent intent)
{
    if(binder == null)
        binder = new AccessibilityServiceBinder (this);

    return binder;
}
```

For more info read the Xamarin docs on bound services, they're very well explained: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/services/part_2_-_bound_services/

**EDIT: Total wrong answer (I will delete it in some minutes). It seems it's not possible to bind to an Accessibility service. More info here: [android bind to AccessibilityService](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9683927/android-bind-to-accessibilityservice)**

Comment: Thank you, but it said that OnBind is sealed and cannot be overriden...

Comment: AccessibilityServiceClass inherits Android.AccessibilityServices.AccessibilityService, not Android.App.Service

Comment: Yes, my fault, for what I see the internal implementation creates an IAccessibilityServiceClientWrapper (source here: https://sourcegraph.com/android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/-/info/JavaArtifact/AndroidSDK/-/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService:type/onBind:android.content.Intent) so I suppose accesibility services aren't supposed to be binded, some other posts state this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9683927/android-bind-to-accessibilityservice)